# how to set session auth token in react native

Tags: react-native, authorization

I am trying to set up a session in my react native
I am new to mobile app development. I don't know whether this is the correct approach to set a session
I am coming from react js background so I tried this approach but in the application tab in react native debugger I dont find the session token set can someone explain and help me whether this is a correct approach

```
  axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
      data: Data56,
    });
    .then(function (response) {
           storeData(response.data.token);
          alert('sucess');
      .catch(error => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error.response, 'catch'));
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

While handling tokens it's better to use `react-native-keychain`. It is more secure than async storage and better for storing sensitive data.

install and import keychain :

```
npm i react-native-keychain --legacy-peer-deps

import * as Keychain from 'react-native-keychain';
```

In your case try this approach :

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register',
    data: Data56,
  });
  .then(async function (response) {
        storeData(response.data.token);
        await Keychain.setGenericPassword(response.data.token);
        alert('sucess');
    .catch(error => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error.response, 'catch'));
    });
}
```

If your tokens are not strings and you need to store an Object, just stringify them using

```
JSON.stringify(response.data.token)
```

and retrieve the token anywhere using :

```
const token = await Keychain.getGenericPassword();
```

You can also reset a session easily using :

```
await Keychain.resetGenericPassword();
```

Answer (score 0):

first install

```
     npm install react-client-session --save
```

Then

```
import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session';


function Login() {
   ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage");
   ReactSession.set("username", "Meon");

   return (
      <div>
       <Switch>
        // Routes 
       </Switch>
    </div>
   );
  }

   export default Login;
```

Then Call your session anywhere as like this

```
    const loggedIn = ReactSession.get("username");
```

Comment: code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: sukprsavam@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"18.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!

Comment: i am getting this error when i try to install package

Comment: @meon first install npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps then run command for session

Comment: oke but now getting thiss error  Error: Unable to resolve module react-client-session from C:\Users\vivek\sukprsavam\components\signupfor.jsx: react-client-session could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules

Comment: @meon you installed eact-client-session --save?

Comment: npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps i did this

Comment: @meon first set session value then on next page where you are calling session import { ReactSession } from 'react-client-session'; then ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage"); and const username = ReactSession.get("username");

Comment: `first set session value`  how to do this

Comment: ReactSession.set("username", "meon");

Comment: i added  `ReactSession.setStoreType("localStorage");
   ReactSession.set("username", "Meon");`  inside then of axios and i am getiing this `error Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`  @Muhammad

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@react-native-async-storage/async-storage](https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/install/) library for storing your **AUTH_TOKEN**. Here is the code with explanation.

When user login your api would return a token that you can store the in the AysncStorage.

```
const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_token', value)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

and with this function you can get your token.

```
const [auth_token, setAuthToken ] = useState(null); 
const getData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token')
    if(value !== null) {
      setAuthToken(value)
    }
  } catch(e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

Here you can use it like this.

```
 axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register', Data56)
      .then(function (response) {
         storeData(réponse.token)
      })
      .catch(error => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error.response, 'catch'));
      });
  }
```

After you set your token , on the start of the application  get the token and store it the redux-store. of the token is null redirect user to login else redirect to Home Screen .

on API call use can use that token like this.

```
var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://my.api.url.com//v1/delete_user_account.php?id=98744',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth_token}`, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: i am not using redux so i doubt this method will work for me

Comment: redux is not mandatory. every time you call your api you have to get then token form async storage like this.  let my_auth_token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_token')

Comment: storeData(réponse.token) where does this get stored? is there any method to check if it is stored?

Comment: i added a alert() after  storeData(réponse.token)  but alert is not working i am not sure  it is woeking i have updated question what i have tryed

Comment: have u install this package. @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Comment: the data is stored in AysncStorage.

Comment: yes i have installed  @react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Comment: but i am not sure the token is getting stroed

Comment: okay I am editing answer just to show to to add and get token .

Comment: did u edit the answer?i  don t find any differnce

Comment: I have added another answer. please look at this.

Comment: the issue is that the token is generted in the `then` part of the axios so i am not able to load   `AsyncStorage.setItem('token', `${value}`)` inside`then` of axios

Comment: can you share response of your api.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code where you can store a token and get that token back.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React from 'react';
import {Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {SafeAreaProvider} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
const App = () => {
  const auth_session_token = 'AwdcE39dsC#43d@2023jlkre2DWjKLD';
  const store_token = (async = value => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', `${value}`)
      .then(() => {
        alert('token is stored');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert('some Error', JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  });

  const get_auth_token = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      .then(token => {
        console.log(token);
        alert(JSON.stringify(token));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Some Eorr');
        alert('THere is some error', JSON.stringify(err));
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => store_token(auth_session_token)}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#0090FF',
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Store Token</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => get_auth_token()}
        style={{
          width: 200,
          height: 50,
          marginTop: 60,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          backgroundColor: '#0090FF',
        }}>
        <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Get Token</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple way using the Async Storage it's similar window.localStorage.

Install React Native Async Storage

```
npm install @react-native-async-storage/async-storage --save
```

Now make a api helper name with api.js

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import axios from 'axios';
export let BASE_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/'
export let GET = async (params)=>{
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
return axios({method:'GET', url:BASE_URL+params, 
    headers: {
      Authorization: token, //here use Bearer token with prefix
    }
  })
}
 export let POST = async (endpoint,params)=>{
let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@token')
return axios({
    method:'POST', 
    url:BASE_URL+endpoint, 
    headers: {
      Authorization: token, //here use Bearer token with prefix
    }, 
    data:JSON.stringify(params)
  })
}
```

Now store the token into the Async Storage

```
 import {POST} from "./helper/api"
 import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
      POST('register',Data56).then(function (response) {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('@token',response.data.token)
        alert('sucess');
    }).catch(error => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(error.response, 'catch'));
    });
   }
```

After the storing a token in async storage next api will call with auth token